# Message not fully read (request) for [0] and action [], resetting Exeception in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have configure Elasticsearch in 3 node on different sever. After restarting elasticsearch nodes, In one elasticsearch node getting Exception `Message not fully read (request) for [0] and action [], resetting`.

Does anyone face similar issue?
My   ES version is `1.3.0`
    JVM version is `1.7.0_65`

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you're having a client somewhere that has a different version. When the client and the elasticsearch server have different versions, this happens. Try to use a little tcpdump and find out! :)

Take a look here: https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/5178